# Driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, system-properties

I am using Selenium for automating the tests. My application exclusively uses IE, it will not work on other Browsers.

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String sUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";                             
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\vthaduri\\workspace\\LDCSuite\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver oWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        oWebDriver.get(sUrl);
        WebElement oSearchInputElem = oWebDriver.findElement(By.name("q")); // Use name locator to identify the search input field.
        oSearchInputElem.sendKeys("Selenium 2");
        WebElement oGoogleSearchBtn = oWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnG']"));  
        oGoogleSearchBtn.click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        oWebDriver.close();
    }    
}
```

And here is the error I am getting

*The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
Jun 12, 2012 4:18:42 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Jun 12, 2012 4:18:42 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute*

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Not sure why I can't post an answer for this, but you can also get around this by specifying the folder location within the PATH Environment value on the machine in question.  This is handy should you want to or have to have the files stored in different places on different machines in different environments

Comment: Replace the line  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\vthaduri\\workspace\\LDCSuite\\IEDriverServer.exe");   by   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\vthaduri\\workspace\\LDCSuite\\IEDriverServer.exe");

Comment: You have set property for chrome instead of IE. this is only the problem

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. You will need InternetExplorer driver executable on your system. So download it from the hinted source (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) unpack it and place somewhere you can find it. In my example, I will assume you will place it to `C:\Selenium\iexploredriver.exe`
2. Then you have to set it up in the system. Here is the Java code pasted from my Selenium project:

   ```
   File file = new File("C:/Selenium/iexploredriver.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   ```

Basically, you have to set this property **before** you initialize driver

Comment: Side note - I am using Chrome, so the code will probably need some tweaks to it. Especially the init part of IE

Comment: I have already added the code in my program. Look at my code in the question. But I am not sure how to get rid of System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\vthaduri\\workspace\\LDCSuite\\IEDriverServer.exe");
     WebDriver oWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: just replace the `webdriver.chrome.driver` with `webdriver.ie.driver`and it should work

Comment: My code:
File file = new File("F:\\SoftwareDownload_Ripon\\WebDriver\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.24.2\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

It works but the error is:
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

What’s the way to solve the problem?

Comment: Ripon - maybe write another question. Its hard to read from comment what you wanted to do

Comment: On my machine I had to start the IE driver server on a port and register it to Remoteweb Driver, then it worked. Merely setting the web driver path was not helping me.

Answer (score 13):

The error message says

> "The path to the driver executable must be set by the
>   **webdriver.ie.driver** system property;"

You are setting the path for the Chrome Driver with "**webdriver.chrome.driver**" property.  You are not setting the file location when for InternetExplorerDriver, to do that you must set "**webdriver.ie.driver**" property.

You can set these properties in your shell, via maven, or your IDE with the -DpropertyName=Value

```
-Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:/.../IEDriverServer.exe"
```

You need to use quotes because of spaces or slashes in your path on windows machines, or alternatively reverse the slashes other wise they are the string string escape prefix.

You could also use

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:/.../IEDriverServer.exe");
```

inside your code.

Comment: Yes, this is the wrong. You have written the code as: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\vthaduri\\workspace\\LDCSuite\\IEDriverServer.exe"); Please use  "webdriver.chrome.driver" instead of "webdriver.chrome.driver"

Answer (score 2):

I just put the driver files directly into my project to not get any dependency to my local machine.

```
final File file = new File("driver/chromedriver_2_22_mac");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

For spring :

```
File inputFile = new ClassPathResource("\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe").getFile();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",inputFile.getCanonicalPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need have to download InternetExplorer driver executable on your system, download it from the source (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) after download unzip it and put on the place of somewhere in your computer. In my example, I will place it to D:\iexploredriver.exe

Then you have write below code in your eclipse main class

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:/iexploredriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```