# Selenium test with Python in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have written a script that opens a web browser using python and Selenium. It works fine with Firefox using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

When I replace Firefox with IE (the suggested value when I start typing), I get the message `IEDriver executable needs to be available in the path.`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.IE()
```

Comment: Here is your answer.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682169/unable-to-launch-internet-explorer-through-webdriver

Comment: @m170897017 Ha. Beat me to it!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Download IE Drivers based on your OS (Windows 32 or 64 bit)

   a. [Download](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip) Windows 32 bits driver

   OR

   b. [Download](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip) Windows 64 bits driver
2. Extract the zip and copy IEDriverServer.exe file to some location e.g. E:\IEDriver
3. Write the following script

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   browser = webdriver.Ie("e:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")
   ```
4. Run the script, it should open IE browser...

Comment: This worked, but the text entering on IE is incredibly slow (1 character per 4 seconds). I am using 64 bit IE with 64 or 32 IEDriverServer. I also tried using an IE tab plugin for Firefox, but Selenium seems to disable add-ins. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: @user2242044 - This issue is already being discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116)

Comment: people who are complaining that sendkeys is very slow. Use 32 bit IE.

Answer (score 5):

**Selenium with Python bindings in IE:**

There are 2 ways to run Selenium python tests in Internet Explorer. I'm considering Windows (Windows 10 in my case):

Prerequisite: Download IE Driver based on your OS from the site: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

[32 bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.zip)

[64 bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0.zip)

***Way 1:***

i) Extract the downloaded zip file in a directory/location of your choice
ii) Set the executable path in your code as below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='D:\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\Drivers\IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0\IEDriverServer.exe')
```

*OR,*

```
self.driver = webdriver.Ie("D:\\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\\Drivers\IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

***Way 2:***

i) Simply paste the IEDriverServer.exe under /Python/Scripts/ (In my case the folder was: C:\Python36\Scripts)
ii) Now write the simple code as below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Ie()
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly that. Selenium **needs** the executable to work with IE. 

A quick google search led me to [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings). You need to download the executable and place it somewhere *visible*. Also, taking a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) should help clear some things about PATH variables.

Answer (score 1):

In selenium 4 you would need to use service method otherwise you would get depreciated error:  You no longer need to download IE driver.
Here are compatible codes for Selenium 4.x IE:

```
# Internet Explorer Browser version
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(executable_path=IEDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```