# How to resolve Selenium with Python: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, module, typeerror, callable

I am new to Selenium/Python and practicing few exercises. I am receiving below error when running my Selenium/Python program in pycharm. Please help.

```
C:\Users\rk.marav\PycharmProjects\RadhaSelenium\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rk.marav/PycharmProjects/RadhaSelenium/Tests/mainTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rk.marav/PycharmProjects/RadhaSelenium/Tests/mainTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    m.main()
  File "C:/Users/rk.marav/PycharmProjects/RadhaSelenium/Tests/mainTest.py", line 10, in main
    driver.getbrowserInstance()
  File "C:\Users\rk.marav\PycharmProjects\RadhaSelenium\executionEngine\DriverScript.py", line 25, in getbrowserInstance
    driver = webdriver.ie(executable_path='C:/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Main Test started...
IE
Browser invoke started

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is my code:

**DriverScript.py:**

```
class driverScript:

    def __init__(self,browser=None):
         if browser is None:
             browser = {}
         else:
             self.browser = browser
             print(self.browser)

         #self.constants = Constants()

    def getbrowserInstance(self):
        # create a new IE session
        print("Browser invoke started")
        if (self.browser=='IE'):
           driver = webdriver.ie(executable_path='C:/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe')
           driver.maximize_window()
           driver.implicitly_wait(5)
           driver.delete.allcookies()
           print("Browser is Invoked")
           driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa"
                       ".com")
```

**mainTest.py**

```
from executionEngine.DriverScript import driverScript
from Utilities.Constants import Constants
from selenium import webdriver

class mainTest(driverScript):

    def main(self):
        print("Main Test started...")
        driver = driverScript('IE')
        driver.getbrowserInstance()

m = mainTest()
m.main()
```

Comment: `webdriver.ie` is a module.  You're calling the wrong thing.  You want `webdriver.Ie` instead (note the capital `I`.)  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925868/494134 for more details.

Comment: Capital letters matter

Comment: why don't you inherit the class Selenium?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I’m voting to close this since it appears to be a typo/trivial.

Comment: Thanks John.  Very much appreciated. Thats resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
    driver = webdriver.ie(executable_path='C:/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that the **webdriver.ie** is a module and is not **callable**.

@JohnGordon was pretty correct in his analysis. **`selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver`** is one of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) related [Python Module](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/py-modindex.html) and is not **callable**.

To initiate an [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) session through [selenium-iedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-iedriver) you need to replace the small `i` with capital **`I`**. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\Selenium\Drivers\IEDriverServer.exe')
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver(“C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)