# How to set path for executable IE drivers in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the following code on my machine (win XP & IE8)

```
public class bookie {                
  private WebDriver driver;        
  private String baseUrl;         
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;        
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();        

  @Before    
  public void setUp() throws Exception {    
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();    
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);    
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);     
    baseUrl = "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/";     
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
  }

  @Test     
  public void testbookie() throws Exception {    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");    
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");    
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Chapter1")).click();    
    driver.findElement(By.id("radiobutton")).click();    
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selecttype"))).selectByVisibleText("Selenium Core");    
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home Page")).click();     
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Chapter2")).click();    
    driver.findElement(By.id("but1")).click();     
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sibling Button']")).click();     
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Index")).click();      
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Chapter1")).click();     
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selecttype"))).selectByVisibleText("Selenium Grid");     
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home Page")).click();      
    driver.quit();
  }
```

**But the stack trace which i was provided is**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$1(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.build(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:230)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:263)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:159)
>     at bookie.setUp(bookie.java:19)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)

Comment: Since you have not specified an *exact* path for the IEDriver, it's going to look in your PATH variable and probably the current working directory. I'd also advise to remove the instability settings you've set.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response Arran.. 
Everything is working fine now.. but still i would like to study/understand things more closely.

so.. I understood most of what u said.. except for the "instability settings" part. 

would u please elaborate.. m a newbie..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the driver in some location like
C:\Selenium\iexploredriver.exe

Then

```
File file = new File("C:/Selenium/iexploredriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Below line should be first line of setUp() function

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Comment: the driver I have is IEDriverServer.exe so i inserted that but then on executing the code, 2 IE windows are opening, none related to base url. and the console reads :
INFO: Retrying request
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.39.0.0
Listening on port 33671
Jan 24, 2014 12:06:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception(org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
Jan 24, 2014 12:06:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the above solution but with Desired Capabilities

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
dc.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);  //If IE fail to work, please remove this and remove enable protected mode for all the 4 zones from Internet options
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);
```