# Errors getting webdriver executables to work with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am having trouble getting the ChromeDriver and IEDriverServer to be recognized from the Java project I am setting up.  The executables have been downloaded and added to C:\Tools\selenium\drivers and that has been added to the path variable (Windows).  How ever when I try to run the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class MarketLeaderHomePage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


        driver.get("myURL");
```

I get the error "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;".  I can set the property to specify the driver path explicitly but my understanding was if the driver exes were added as part of the path I should not have to do this.  I am new to Java so I am wondering if there is something that I am missing that needs to be done with regards to the package or the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

> The [InternetExplorerDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) is a standalone server which implements
>   WebDriver's wire protocol.  You do not need to run an installer before
>   using the InternetExplorerDriver, though some configuration is
>   required. The standalone server executable must be downloaded from the
>   Downloads page and placed in your PATH.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property). The same goes with chrome, it is also a standalone, [reference](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Comment: @Erik - Thanks, but that is not the issue.  I realize the drivers are both stand alone and I had already unpacked them into a directory and added it to the directory.  I am still getting the error unless I specify the path the the driver explicitly with the System.setProperty method.  My understanding was that is the executables are in the path I should not have to specify them in the code.