# Can not run tests using protractor on IE11

Tags: selenium, protractor

```
 WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest versio
elenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)
    at C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
    at C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
    at C:\Users\vivekb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:9)
```

getting some issue while running tests on IE.

In the server console i can see

```
16:47:34.080 WARN - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloade
d from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

added property in config file. is the correct way to set it

```
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\IEDriverServer.exe'],
```

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property