# How to control selection of Internet Explorer Driver 32bit from Serenity BDD

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, selenium-iedriver

Currently I have IEDriver 32 and 64 bit executable files in m system path. When I initiate tests from Serenity BDD it automatically selects 64bit version. Can I control this selection using any specific property?

Comment: I can see using Selenium it can be done like 
`System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath)`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a serenity.properties file in the Serenity root dir. Then add these below:

```
webdriver.driver=ie
webdriver.ie.driver=path to 32/64 bit IE Driver exe
```

This should fix your issues.