# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Tags: java, selenium

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with Selenium 3.x you have to download **chromedriver.exe** from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and save it in your machine. Next you have to mention the absolute path of the **chromedriver.exe** through `System.setProperty`. While you mention the absolute path of the **chromedriver.exe** through `System.setProperty` you have either provide front slashes "**/**" or esacpe the back slases "**\\**". Here is your own working code with some simple tweaks:

```
public class first 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/your_directory/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver dr1= new ChromeDriver(); ;
        dr1.get("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question