# Unable to load IE Browser in Cucumber ,Java Framework

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Unable to load IE Browser in Cucumber ,Java Framework

Serenity Properties File

```
webdriver.driver=iexplorer
webdriver.ie.driver = C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe
```

When Running the test getting Exception Stating Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property

Comment: Check this
[Driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995314/driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-ie-driver-system-property)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the path with 
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", C:\Selenium\IEDriverServer.exe);